# Custom Button to copy data from Opportunity into a related custom object

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, apex-code

I have a custom object that is used for product setup that is mapped to an opportunity. It's a one to many relationship - one opportunity maps to many setup objects, but one setup object is only mapped to one opportunity.

Opportunity has some setup fields that need to act as defaults for the related custom object. Unfortunately, I cannot just specify them in a formula - getting an error.

What I would like to do is have a custom button that would allow user to click and copy all of the related setup fields from the opportunity into the custom setup object and then edit them as needed.

Any pointers or sample code are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this with a custom button on the related list for your custom object on the opportunity detail page.

All of the fields on a standard Salesforce new/edit screen have id's associated with them. You can specify values for fields by using these ids to set GET parameters on your URL. For example if the id on the name field on your opportunity is 'opp3', the following URL will populate the name field on your new opportunity page:

```
https://na2.salesforce.com/006/e?opp3=Hello+World
```

You would have to change na2 to the correct server for your org.

The new record page URL contains the 3 character id prefix for your particular object and then '/e'. 006 is the prefix for opportunities. You will have to attempt to create a new record to see what the 3 characters are for your custom object.

You will have to capture the id's of the fields you want to populate on your custom object. You can do this by viewing the source of the new record page. For custom fields these id's will take the form of a Salesforce Id (eg. 00N40000002QhEV).

Create a new list button on your custom object and set the behavior to without header and sidebar and set the source to URL. Build up your URL with id=value pairs separated by '&' using the id you got from the page source and the insert field functionality to select the opportunity fields your wish to add in. You should end up with something like this:

```
/a0U/e?00N40000002QhEV={!Opportunity.Name}&00N40000002QhEW={!Opportunity.StageName}
```

a0U should be replaced by the correct prefix for your custom object. Then add your button to the related list for your custom object under opportunity.

Comment: Thank you! Will try this today or tomorrow.

Comment: After trying this out and playing with it, this solution does not "Copy" stuff over if the object already exists. However, it works great for a new object and is similar to the question I asked before. I'll still accept it, since this was helpful, and no one else has stepped up.