# Prepopulate fields in Salesforce.com

Tags: salesforce, custom-fields

I have a doubt, i've been working with salesforce for a while and now i have a requirement from a customer.

They need that some custom fields be populated with a value of parent object, making some research on stackoverflow, i found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5334585/custom-button-to-copy-data-from-opportunity-into-a-related-custom-object#_=_), but this isn't working for me because my project is a manage package and when this is installed on a another salesforce instance the id of custom field change.

if someone could help me, I will be grateful.

Thanks!.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your problem — do you want to populate the lookup to the parent object, or pre-fill some fields on the child when the parent is specified?

Comment: Hi, i'm trying to fre-fill some fields on the child when parent is specified

Comment: I can't see any way of doing the same as that post without using the IDs unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see any way of doing the same as that post without using the IDs, I was thinking you could route via a VF page and build up the URL in the controller but it doesn't seem as though you can get the IDs of fields, just their type etc..

I think the best you could do in this instance is to override the default new recordpage with a visualforce page. In the constructor of your controller you could then loop through the page parameters and pre-fill the corresponding fields on the new record before it's displayed on screen. Using fieldsets or just an `<apex:Detail>` component would keep the level of effort down and also maximise the flexibility of the page for the end users.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i just talket with my customer and they don't want to build a custom visualforce page.